# flooring Calculator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I have a calculator where the user uses a dropdown menu to select a type of floor, and then adds the width of the wood, the width of the room and the length of the room, and I am trying to display it in a box, however when I click calculate it, nothing appears in the box.

I have tried using a input text box to output the value, I have tried to use a form output, I believe that the problem is in my calculator in my java script, the reason for this is that the dropdown menu's work in html. I tried running the calculation without the dropdown menu, therefore bypassing the switch statement.

Below is my html code

```
<body>
<th>Plank Calculator</th>
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <td>Choose flooring type:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="wood" name="wood" value="-choose floor type-">
                <option value="0" rel="laminate">laminate</option>
                <option value="1" rel="solid">solid</option>
                <option value="2" rel="engineered">engineered</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Choose wood:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="items" class="cascade" onChange="colour(this.value);">
                <option value="3" class="laminate">doc loc junior natural oak</option>
                <option value="4" class="laminate">doc loc senior natural oak</option>
                <option value="5" class="solid">natural oak</option>
                <option value="6" class="solid">rustic oak</option>
                <option value="7" class="engineered">natural oak lacquered</option>
                <option value="8" class="engineered">rustic oak lacquered</option>`</select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <form>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Length of room:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="l" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Width of room:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="w" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>number of packs needed</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="packs" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <output name="packs" for ="w l"></output>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
<button id="calculate">calculate</button>
```

Below is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $cat = $('select[name=wood]'),
    $items = $('select[name=items]');

$cat.change(function () {
    var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
        rel = $this.attr('rel'),
        $set = $items.find('option.' + rel);

    if ($set.size() < 0) {
        $items.hide();
        return;
    }

    $items.show().find('option').hide();

    $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
});
$("#calculate").click(function () {
    var RLength = document.getElementById("l");
    var RWidth = document.getElementById("w");
    var packs = document.getElementById("packs");
    var length = RLength.value;
    var width = RWidth.value;
    var packs1 = "";
    ans = (parseInt(width, 10) + parseInt(length, 10));
    packs1 = Integer.toString(ans);
    packs.value = "packs1";

});});function colour(inobj) {


switch (inobj) {

    case "3":
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;

    case "4":
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;

    case "5":
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;

    case "6":
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;

    case "7":
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;
    case "8":
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;
    default:
        bl = "1900";
        bt = "7";
        bw = "125";
        break;
}
var bl = "";
var bt = "";
var bw = "";
var ans = $("#total");}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *nothing happens* is a start, but not of a question. You should instead attempt to debug the issue yourself first. If you are not successful, you should then ask, sharing your debugging attempts. For instance, have you narrowed down the issue to either the JS or HTML?

Comment: There is a lot of things not working on this code.  Some problems: 

- The $("#calculate").click need to be in the $(document).ready
- var RLength = document.getElementById("l"), there is not element with Id "l"
- On the line: "ans = bw+(parseInt(w, 10) + parseInt(l, 10));" the var w and l are never declare
- ...

Comment: @Boaz the problem is with JS, I have tried excluding the dropdown menu completely.

Comment: @forumma I have fixed those problems thank you, the code is still not working, will keep trying, if you see any more problems, would you mind letting me know.

Comment: BTW I am a complete novice, never programmed in html before until Tuesday evening so I am sorry if their are a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty good for a first attempt!

http://jsfiddle.net/PeteA/82yk7L36/1/

The above shows various bits.  The key points is that you were using

```
document.getElementById('l')
```

But your L and W inputs didn't have an ID value (only a name).

I've also tidied up the html a little.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more question, my next step is to add the bw with length and width, I tried just putting 

ans = bw+(parseInt(width, 10) + parseInt(length, 10)); but then my original problem comes back, what am I doing wrong. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I take it bw, bl and bt are the length and width of a board?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeteA/82yk7L36/3/  I've added pack size in as well, so it'll calculate out the number of boards required and the number of packs.  It'll need some validation added in at some point but it's a reasonable start :)

Comment: Hello pete,
I have updated a new fiddle, but it is not working, the laminate is working but the solid and engineered is not, would you mind having a look, it is probably something simple, that I can't see, warning the code is very long.

that is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/luckoftheirish/ma85xjw0/

Comment: Working OK for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/PeteA/ma85xjw0/1/  I did have to select jQuery from the drop down on the left to get it running though.

Comment: strange it is not working for me, I should have 17 engineered, but I can only choose 1, is that occuring on your browser?

Comment: Ah, in which case it wasn't :D  Not all browsers support hiding options equally.  You're best off `        items.find('option').prop('disabled',true);'
'        $set.prop('disabled', false);` as so: http://jsfiddle.net/PeteA/ma85xjw0/2/